# Why can't I find a color changing GU24 bulb?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

Do they even make color changing GU24 bulbs?? I am looking for one for the holidays and can't find any! It seems like I could buy a color changing edison bulb and then get a GU24 adapter to screw it into. But that sounds hazardous, is it safe?

Comment: why does your post title not reflect the actual question about the adapter ... asking about color changing GU24 bulbs is just clutter in your post that gets your question closed

Answer (score 2):

GU24 to Edison Screw adapters are absolutely fine provided they are rated for the electrical load you will be putting through them, and designed for heat resistance. Most I've seen are rated up to 150 watts, which is far more than you need - most LED bulbs are 10 watts maximum. So get good quality adapters and you'll be fine. Keep in mind that these adapters could make the bulbs stick out a bit.